# Where does useState store it's value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react, but I didn't find an answer to my question on the web, I believe I misunderstand a plenty of things. 
Take a look at this code

```js
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={main}>
      <Router>
        <CssBaseline />
        <TopBar onMenuButton={() => setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)} />
        <AppMenu open={menuOpen} />
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar} />
          <Grid container justify="center" spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={menuOpen ? 10 : 12}>
              <Routes />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </main>
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

At the top we call `useState` hook and it return two values: a variable and a function which updates a variable. When `setMenuOpen` gets called the component is re-rendered. When a component is re-rendered the whole `App` function is called one more time and `useState` at the very top is called one more time.  
The question is: how does `useState` knows about that new value being passed to `setMenuItem` function when we get to this place second time? So now, `menuOpen` is equal to what we passed as an argument to `setMenuItem` function.

```js
const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)
```

I believe it stores it in some kind of registry or a global variable between different renders of component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://pomb.us/build-your-own-react/ You can follow a step by step creation of React.

Comment: @Twiggeh very interesting. I believe I'm getting it.